# Rails 5.1 button_to helper produces query string instead of hidden form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, parameters

this is my first try on stackoverflow, so bear with me please...

I am trying to generate a kind of preview page in Rails in the fashion of:

1. Fill in a Form
2. Send the form to the controller
3. Get a view displaying back the data you just sent plus some additional data generated by the controller from your form input
   4 push a button to confirm the data is correct
4. NOW save everything to the database.

Current status is: I have the form post to a preview action on the controller, do my magic there and render a preview view.
In that view I display all my data (which comes out of the controller as one object with a collection of nested objects inside).
To pass the data back after verification, I tried to use a simple button.
As I understand the "button_to" helper, I am supposed to pass my params hash to the helper to get all my params in a set of hidden fields inside the one-button form.
However, my button for some reason does only contain a hidden field for the authenticity token. All other parameters are appended to the query string of the action on the form.

My button code:

```
<%= button_to(:submit, :action => :create, params: @event_registration.as_json(root: true, include: :participants)) %>
```

The generated source code:

```
<form class="button_to" method="post" action="/en/event_registrations?event_registration%5Bcreated_at%5D=&amp;event_registration%5Bevent_id%5D=1&amp;event_registration%5Bid%5D=&amp;event_registration%5Bparticipants%5D%5B%5D%5Bbirthdate%5D=2017-12-27&amp;event_registration%5Bparticipants%5D%5B%5D%5Bcountry%5D=DE&amp;event_registration%5Bparticipants%5D%5B%5D%5Bcreated_at%5D=&amp;event_registration%5Bparticipants%5D%5B%5D%5Bemail%5D=&amp;event_registration%5Bparticipants%5D%5B%5D%5Bfirst_name%5D=&amp;event_registration%5Bparticipants%5D%5B%5D%5Bid%5D=&amp;event_registration%5Bparticipants%5D%5B%5D%5Blast_name%5D=&amp;event_registration%5Bparticipants%5D%5B%5D%5Bnickname%5D=&amp;event_registration%5Bparticipants%5D%5B%5D%5Bpostcode%5D=&amp;event_registration%5Bparticipants%5D%5B%5D%5Bupdated_at%5D=&amp;event_registration%5Bupdated_at%5D=&amp;event_registration%5Buser_id%5D=1"><input type="submit" value="submit" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="A/jV9kY3UYSsYeF9j2+JEsL4XPAixGBYtX47shTsIp5XK5Dq2tdZsQz2KrQOzcJP6roHCEROTF+n6cYyu/iICw==" /></form>
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the [documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to) for `button_to`:

> button_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block)

It looks like you're passing `params` as part of `options`. You should pass them as part of `html_options`. When you pass them as `options`, you're passing them as part of the path.

Try this instead:

```
<%= button_to(:submit, { :action => :create }, params: @event_registration.as_json(root: true, include: :participants)) %>
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! 
Sometimes you get quite blind when staring at your code and documentation for too long...

Comment: Totally. I've been bitten by this same thing a number of times over the years.